# WPF What does + sign do in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I recently had a very interesting scenario, and was wandering if someone can explain to me the meaning of + in xaml if it has any.
Note: I am using VS2010
Below is my datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModel}">
   <Border Style="{StaticResource CmyTheme}" 
             PreviewMouseDown="My_OnPreviewMouseDown" x:Name="myBorder">
            ...
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myList}" >
           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Name="myListSP" />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>+
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see following the `</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>`  tag is **+** sign, now when the when the code was compile it never complained about this + sign so I didn't realise it was there. Then my programme ran fine up to the point it was required to used the DataTemplate which I then received an Error: **Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead**.
Anyway I have gone ahead and removed the + sign and it all works fine. However I am curious about the reason the compiler never complained about the +? Does the + have a meaning in xaml?

Comment: There's nothing special about `+`. Rather, if you include text within the `ItemsControl` tag, then it thinks you want that text to be one of the items. However, since you've already set `ItemsSource`, you can't also just add elements manually, and so you get that exception.

Comment: Ha figure that, well that was just silly :/ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dlev said, in your case the `+` is just an item in the list which conflicts with the `ItemsSource` binding. It could be any other character, string or object just as well.

However, there is a special meaning of the '+' sign in XAML and though it has nothing to do with your particular case, it might be interesting for others coming across the question and nice to know for you.

Consider a nested class structure, such as

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Foo { get; set; }

    public class Child
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In WPF, the type `Parent.Child` (C#) translates to `Parent+Child` (XAML) and can be used with `{x:Type ...}`. For example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Parent+Child}" />
```

Just for completeness, maybe it's interesting for somebody...